# How to clear data-placeholder value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input field

```
<span class="total_round_size inline-notoolbar-editable" data-placeholder="000,000">{{ deal.total_round_size|intcomma|safe }}</span>
```

When I change another input, data is copied to this, but original text ("000,000") is still there and overlaps with new text. How to remove it? I tried several ways, but nothing works:

```
    $('.total_round_size').attr('showing-placeholder', '');
    $('.total_round_size').innerHTML = "";
    $('.total_round_size').text("");
    $('.total_round_size').html() = "";
    $('input[name=total_round_size]').val("");
```

It's desirable not to change structure of the span (not to add  element for example).

EDIT:
More details

```
function parse(elem_name) {
    return parseInt($(elem_name).html().replace(/[\.,,]/g,''));
}
$('#target').change(function() {
    $('.total_round_size').text(parse('.target'));
});

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="pull-left">{% trans "Total Round Size" %}:</div>
        <div class="pull-left">&nbsp;€&nbsp;<span class="total_round_size inline-notoolbar-editable" data-placeholder="000,000">{{ deal.total_round_size|intcomma|safe }}{% if not deal.total_round_size %}<br/>{% endif %}</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Target is substantially the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `showing-placeholder` to `data-placeholder` here:

```
$('.total_round_size').attr('data-placeholder','');
```

since you've assigned the value to `data-placeholder` attribute, not `showing-placeholder`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it's working well:**

```
$('.total_round_size').removeAttr('data-placeholder');
```

**or**

```
$('.total_round_size').attr('data-placeholder','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.total_round_size').attr('data-placeholder', '');
```

Comment: what is the reason behind down voting.